# Popolate collection from external file, then close file, and show collection items

Tags: excel, vba, loops, collections

Is possible to popolate one pubblic collection from one external file?!?!?
I can't show the collection items,
to test this code I tried to loop the collection's item then
if the loop is before close the wb source, the result show right
but if I close che wb source I can only count the items collection.item = 31 (right result) if I try debug.print collection(x) 'x are integer from 1 to 31

I retrieve only Error 424.
Is my code, wrong, or is not possible to polulate one collection from an external file and, in this case what I've to use?!?!

Below my code:

```
option explicit
public Belts as collection
Public Sub mCaricaBelts()
On Error GoTo RigaErrore
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbn As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range, v As Variant
    Dim lrw As Long
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlManual
        .StatusBar = _
            "Sto caricato la tabella Fasce"
    End With
    wbn = "Listino.xlsx"
    If Not Belts Is Nothing Then
        Set Belts = Nothing
    End If
    
    Set Belts = New Collection
    If AlreadyOpen(wbn) Then
        Set wb = Workbooks(wbn)
    Else
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\itcpifs01\license$\Listino.xlsx")
    End If
    Set rng = wb.Worksheets("dbRatesSTD").Range("C1")
    Set rng = Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight))
    For Each c In rng
        Belts.Add c
    Next

' if I put the loop here, I can show results
    For Each v In Belts
       Debug.Print v
    Next


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

' if I put the loop here, I can't show results, Error 424 Object required
    For Each v In Belts
       Debug.Print v
    Next

RigaChiusura:
    Set c = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set sh = Nothing
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlAutomatic
        .StatusBar = ""
    End With
    Exit Sub

RigaErrore:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
    Resume RigaChiusura

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Belts.Add c.Value`, which will add the value in the cell to the collection as opposed to adding a reference to the range object to the collection. The value will still be available after the workbook is closed, as opposed to the reference which will no longer be available.

Comment: Right, to store the value is correct use c.value otherwise sys store only the address(), tnk

Answer (score 0):

## Array version

Don't know much about collections but I think arrays is the way to go.

```
Option Explicit
Public Belts As Variant 'Public Belts As Collection
Public Sub mCaricaBelts()
On Error GoTo RigaErrore
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbn As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range, v As Variant
    Dim lrw As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlManual
        .StatusBar = _
            "Sto caricato la tabella Fasce"
    End With
    wbn = "Listino.xlsx"
'    If Not Belts Is Nothing Then
'        Set Belts = Nothing
'    End If

'    Set Belts = New Collection
    If AlreadyOpen(wbn) Then
        Set wb = Workbooks(wbn)
    Else
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\itcpifs01\license$\Listino.xlsx")
    End If
    Set rng = wb.Worksheets("dbRatesSTD").Range("C1")
    Set rng = Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight))
    'Be careful, this is a horizontal array.
    Belts = rng
'    For Each c In rng
'        Belts.Add c
'    Next

' if I put the loop here, I can show results
    For Each v In Belts
       Debug.Print v
    Next


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

' if I put the loop here, I can't show results, Error 424 Object required
    For Each v In Belts
       Debug.Print v
    Next

RigaChiusura:
    Set c = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set sh = Nothing
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlAutomatic
        .StatusBar = ""
    End With
    Exit Sub

RigaErrore:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
    Resume RigaChiusura

End Sub
```

I have older Excel so I can only imagine what `AlreadyOpen(wbn)` means, but here's the old way for the complete If statement for your code:

```
'Check if Excel file is opened:
On Error Resume Next
  Set wb = Workbooks(wbn) 'Workbook is opened.
  If Err then 'Workbook is closed.
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\itcpifs01\license$\Listino.xlsx")
    Err.Clear
  End If
On Error GoTo RigaErrore 'Reactivate your 'first line error'.
```

There are no constants in your code. I would add this to the beginning of the code and make appropriate changes:

```
Const cStrTabella as String = "Sto caricato la tabella Fasce"
Const cStrWbn as String = "Listino.xlsx"
Const cStrWbp as String = "\\itcpifs01\license$\Listino.xlsx"
Const cStrWs as String = "dbRatesSTD"
Const cStrAddress as String = "C1"
```

Now it's much easier to change stuff and for someone else to modify it for a test and you can much faster get an answer for a problem.